# RuntimeBinderException: More than one type in the binding has the same full name. c#

Tags: c#, .net

I get this error when trying to dynamically cast an object. What does it mean? How do I fix it?

I'm creating an object at runtime using TypeExtender which is a library uses System.Reflection.Emit and depends on Typebuilder to create the dynamic object's type. This is how I use it.

```
 private object createRunTimeCurrencyTable(Type type)
{
    var typeExtender = new TypeExtender("CurrencyEntity", typeof(CurrencyEntityChild));
    typeExtender.AddAttribute<EntityAttribute>(new object[] { $"{type.Name}" });
    typeExtender.AddProperty("ID", typeof(int), typeof(ColumnAttribute), new object[] { "ID", ColumnAttribute.DataType.DOUBLE, true });
    typeExtender.AddProperty("amount", typeof(double), typeof(ColumnAttribute), new object[] { "Amount" , ColumnAttribute.DataType.DOUBLE});
    typeExtender.AddProperty<Currency>("currency");
    var returnedClass = typeExtender.FetchType();
    return Activator.CreateInstance(returnedClass);

}
```

the library says that it creates the type by deriving from the provided type in this case "CurrencyEntity", what I'm  trying to do then is to cast the returned object to its base Type "CurrencyEntity" using the following method

```
dynamic DynamicCast(object entity, Type to)
{
    var openCast = this.GetType().GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var closeCast = openCast.MakeGenericMethod(to);
    return closeCast.Invoke(entity, new[] { entity });
}
static T Cast<T>(object entity) where T : class
{
    return entity as T;
}
```

the cast operation gives me a null object which arise this exception whenever I access its properties.

> RuntimeBinderException: More than one type in the binding has the same full name

Note: I'm using C# on Unity Engine.